# Function within a for loop to be used on button press not changing based on the button used (Python 3.8.6 + Tkinter)

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop, tkinter

thank you in advance for any help.

I am trying to create a dice rolling program where it takes a character's stats from it's class, and uses that to roll a 20 sided dice + their stat modifier. This is also my first time using Tkinter. (full code below)

When I run this code now, it generates exactly how I want it to however, in the for loop, the function roll() will only use the last number from the loop (assigning it a value of 5/charisma) to output the dice roll, regardless of the button used, where as I would like it to use the value from the button used.

Could someone please shed some light on what I'm doing wrong here as I am self-taught and still in the learning process.

Thank you again.

```
import random
import tkinter as tk

class playerCharacter():
    instances = []
    def __init__(self, name, strength, constitution, dexterity, wisdom, intelligence, charisma):
        self.__class__.instances.append(name)
        self.name = name
        self.strength = strength
        self.constitution = constitution
        self.dexterity = dexterity
        self.wisdom = wisdom
        self.intelligence = intelligence
        self.charisma = charisma

Bekeno = playerCharacter('Bekeno', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Forged = playerCharacter('Forged', 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0) #currently unused

character = Bekeno

attributes = {
    "strength": character.strength,
    "constitution": character.constitution,
    "dexterity": character.dexterity,
    "wisdom": character.wisdom,
    "intelligence": character.intelligence,
    "charisma": character.charisma
}

window = tk.Tk() #set up the window of the program
window.title("Dice Roller!")
for i in range(7): #sets the size to be dynamic
    window.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
    window.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

for attribute_name, attribute in attributes.items():
    def roll():
        lbl_output['text']= str('D20 + ' + str(attribute) + ' = ' + str(random.randrange(1,21) + attribute))

    frame = tk.Frame( #container for the widgets
        master=window,
        relief=tk.RAISED,
        borderwidth=2
    )
    frame.pack()
 
    label = tk.Label( #Name of the type of check
        master=frame,
        relief=tk.RIDGE,
        text=attribute_name,
        width=10,
        height=4
    )
    label.grid(column=0, row=0)

    button = tk.Button( #Button to roll the check / show modifier
        master=frame,
        command=roll,
        text="Roll " + attribute_name + " : " + str(attribute),
        width=25,
        height=4
    )
    button.grid(column=1, row=0)

frame_end = tk.Frame()#Output at the bottom for dice rolls
frame_end.pack()

lbl_output = tk.Label(
    master=frame_end,
    text='Good luck!',
    height=4
)
lbl_output.pack()

window.mainloop() #runs the program
```

Comment: Change `def roll()` to `def roll(attribute=attribute)`.

Comment: Thank you so much @acw1668! Instantly resolved my issue and I understand now how this works. Thank you again for your time!